# Get a list of object created for the last days grouped by day

Tags: python, django

I need to get a list of objects that have been created in the last few days, grouped by day, in order to display the data in a chart.

I have this model:

```
class Model(Base):
    ...
    created = DateTimeField(default=timezone.now(), editable=False)
    ...
```

Now I do this:

```
Model.objects.filter(
    created__date__lte=today,
    created__date__gte=today-delta
).values('created').annotate(count=Count('id'))
```

But, I get the following queryset:

```
<SoftDeletableQuerySet [{'created': datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 15, 13, 5, 35, 208157, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'count': 1}, {'created': datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 15, 13, 5, 35, 297617, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'count': 1}, {'created': datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 15, 13, 5, 35, 385555, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'count': 1}, {'created': datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 15, 13, 5, 35, 474287, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'count': 1}, {'created': datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 15, 13, 5, 35, 507464, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'count': 1}, {'created': datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 15, 13, 5, 35, 552092, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'count': 1}, {'created': datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 15, 13, 5, 35, 585314, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'count': 1}, {'created': datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 15, 13, 5, 35, 618656, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'count': 1}, {'created': datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 15, 13, 5, 35, 652501, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'count': 1}, {'created': datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 15, 13, 5, 35, 696849, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'count': 1}]>
```

As you can see, the objects were grouped by creation date, but this field is `DateTimeField`, not `DateField`, therefore, grouped in milliseconds.

I'm trying to do this:

```
Model.objects.filter(
    created__date__lte=today,
    created__date__gte=today-delta
).values('created__date').annotate(count=Count('id'))
```

But I get the following error:

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'date' into field. Join on 'created' not permitted.
```

I think that what I need is quite common, and there must be some kind of DRY way to do this.

Comment: show your models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `.annotate(..)` with an [**`TruncDate`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.TruncDate) expression to truncate to the date:

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate

Model.objects.filter(
    created__date__lte=today,
    created__date__gte=today-delta
).annotate(
    day=TruncDate('created')
).values('day').annotate(
    count=Count('id')
).order_by('day')
```

The `.order_by` is necessary, since otherwise you do not "force" Django to use a `GROUP BY`, and thus the `Count('id')` will not contain the total number of items for that specific day.

Comment: I think the `order_by` trick is not needed for models with no default ordering, but I guess you often want to order by day in any case, so it doesn't hurt. One thing that I don't think is mentioned explicitly in the docs is that `Count()` accepts the special expression `'*'` as its first argument if you only want to count the number of rows. `Count(*)` is part of the SQL standard, so it should work in all database backends, I think.